# ERROR [net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.PdfGsUtilities:convertPdf2Png(109)] (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) Unable to load library 'gs'

Tags: java, linux, tess4j

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using the above dependency in Maven. This is used in Java and eclipse.
But now I want to run my application in linode server.
I get the following error:

> 24-03-2020 11:43:19,577 ERROR 
>   [net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.PdfGsUtilities:convertPdf2Png(109)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) Unable to load library 'gs': Native
>   library (linux-x86-64/libgs.so) not found in resource path
>   (/home/ubuntu/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar)
>       24-03-2020 11:43:20,757 INFO  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2:(121)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) OpenType Layout tables used in font
>   ABCDEE+Calibri,Bold are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
>       24-03-2020 11:43:20,978 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider:loadDiskCache(481)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) New fonts found, font cache will be
>   re-built
>       24-03-2020 11:43:20,978 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider:(233)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) Building on-disk font cache, this may
>   take a while
>       24-03-2020 11:43:21,215 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider:(236)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) Finished building on-disk font cache,
>   found 96 fonts
>       24-03-2020 11:43:21,289 INFO  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2:(121)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) OpenType Layout tables used in font
>   ABCDEE+Calibri are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
>       24-03-2020 11:43:26,339 ERROR [net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract:doOCR(244)]
>   (http-/139.162.55.129:8090-6) null: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.dispose(Tesseract.java:826) [tess4j-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
>         at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:239) [tess4j-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
>         at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:194) [tess4j-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
>         at org.tg.weblayer.traveldesk.controller.TgTesseract.getOCR(TgTesseract.java:32)
>   [classes:]